# What are the common salary raises factors in German software companies?

Tags: software-industry, salary, new-job, germany

I will start my first job as a software developer in a German company soon. Since I've never had a job before, I don't know much how salaries are increased if an increase is going to happen. I'm particularly interested in German companies and software development positions since there is a shortage of us.

My questions:

1. Are there common/standard factors for salary raises? For example, say my salary is 3400€/month and a company is willing to raise my salary after 1 year of working for them, how much would I expect it to be? I mean giving the high taxes in Germany, an increase with 200€ or so is not going to make a difference at all at the end of the month. So I guess the raise factor should be higher.

   I believe German software companies tend to raise the salaries of software developers annually to keep their developers since there is a shortage of us and it's easy to find a higher paying job after one year of experience. It would be great if someone can point out how much the increase factors could be in 5 years period.

   2. I'm expecting to have my salary increased from 3400 to 4000€ by the end of my first year with them, and from 4000 to 5000 by the end of the second year. Is this a realistic expectation in the German software industry?

Comment: Why do you believe there is a shortage of software developers in Germany?

Comment: @Brandin it's a known fact.

Comment: @JackTwain: "known facts" have a way of being *known*, but not necessarily *facts*. Whether there is a shortage of "software developers" (which is a vast field) depends very much on each specific developer's skill set and location.

Comment: @JackTwain [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cckf7mIJKmM) about an alleged "Fachkräftemangel" might be of interest to you

Comment: @inf my German is not that good, yet (improving). But the main message that I understood is that the shortage of workers in the sciences fields is not true? I doubt it, because the number of job postings for software developers for Germany is huge! There is a lot of demand for software developers in Germany!

Comment: @inf i also want to add that it only took me one month to find a decent job! And it took me that long just because my German is bad! If I had  descent German language skills, I would have gotten couple job offers in the first week after graduate or so! Not because I'm good, but because companies are having a bad time finding the right people here! I know a lot of informatik students who can't code!

Comment: @JackTwain Yes, the message is basically that it's one big numbers game from the employers so that more people start CS and that they can pick the best and also attract more foreign talent.

Comment: @inf then it's true that there is indeed a shortage of "skilled" people in IT :)

Comment: unless you're really really good at what you do, your raise expectations are really overrated, was it for staying at the same place or switching jobs. Generally, people tend to consider that a 10% raise is a reasonable amount to start the salary negociation. You usually can't get much more than that. You probably don't want to neither, cause the more you get the more complicated it is to find another job with at least equal compensation.

Comment: Google for    Fachkräftemangel Lüge    and wake up.

Comment: Have you actually calculated this? At your salary, an increase of 200€ will not "not going to make a difference at all at the end of the month", it's 100€ more. That's hardly nothing (especially considering those taxes also pay yourhealthcare, etc.). For the record, I am a software developer in Germany and my raises have always been between 5 and 10%. Asking for 25% will make you seem very out of touch with reality.

Comment: @JackTwain: And there's a huge influx of qualified people from east and southern Europe.

Comment: I nominate this for reopening. This is not about "**company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies**", nor about "**legal advice**". The close reason simply does not fit.

Comment: @JackTwain It changes every year... it's picking up and will continue to pick up as long as unemployment stays low. Refer to https://www.roberthalf.de/gehalt for raise and salary expectations. The U.S. has been out of a recession for a few years now and pay for Java skills are going up 10% this year. The EU isn't as far removed from the recession, but I would expect tech jobs in Germany to pick up the pace in salary increases the next few years. A lot of German software companies are beating revenue forecasts and investment is picking up. Competition + low unemployment = $

Comment: @JackTwain it's too late to edit my comment above, but I wanted to add that in the UK developers are looking at a 6-7.5% raise, Canadians at 5-8.5% raise depending on skills. Developesr in Germany are only looking at 2-5% raise. That's average, so a good company will be above that. As far as comments about there being plenty of people in the rest of the EU that can do the work; this is becoming less true. EU Unemployment has dropped from 11.5 to 10.5 in under a year. 2 years ago it was over 12. If you're not from the EU, getting a visa is difficult. So competition for jobs is dwindling.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Employers in Germans will usually rather think in yearly than in monthly salaries, but let's stick with your monthly figures.

A raise from 3400 to 4000 EUR per month is a 18% raise, one from 4000 to 5000 EUR is a 25% raise. Overall, you are aiming for a 47% raise over two years. This is... *ambitious*. Since you are at the beginning of your career, you may indeed get a higher percentage raise than later on, but a raise of 47% over two years really looks unrealistic to me.

I'd rather expect something in the ball park of 300 EUR in both years, which would translate into 9% in the first and 8% in the second year. Compare this to the current almost-negative rate of inflation, and it's still a lot.

Yes, a lot of that will be eaten up by taxes. Then again, if you profited from a free university education that those taxes paid for, you at least don't have a crippling college debt.

You might be able to command more, of course, if you prove indispensable to your job. Or if you switch jobs. (But job tenure is usually longer in Germany than in the US, so someone who switches after only one year might be perceived as a quitter.)

Comment: @Sumyrda especially if you aspire to do it by switching jobs rather than getting a large raise.

Comment: to be honest I find it quite stupid for employers not to give large raises while we can just leave and find a higher paying job for the sake of getting a higher salary. I mean the cost of giving a large raise would be much lower for the employer/company than having to get a new developer! Because now I'm seriosuly thinking about leaving after gaining two years of experience or so! Because I can easily get 5000€/month after say 2 years of experience or so giving the industry situation. If I were the company I would just give a higher raise to keep their employees!!

Comment: @JackTwain you are assuming that the number of software engineering jobs where you can easily get 5000 eur per month with only 2y experience is widely available. In general that's a false notion many 'recent' college graduates have (mostly based on historical data). That might be true if you're exceptional and are actually able to prove it during those 2 years. But in that case your own employer will likely do something extra also, which might be something else than salary.

Comment: @KillianDS "in that case your own employer will likely do something extra also, which might be something else than salary" - something like what?!

Comment: @JackTwain: more training (both in terms of getting time allocated to it, and of your employer paying for it), sending you to conferences, a nicer environment with better offices, better hard- & software and/or a more interesting technology stack, more interesting career options (like moving into a management, sales or consulting role, if you want to), ... there are *lots* of things an employer can do for you that are non-financial.

Comment: @JackTwain, it is more economical to give lower raises as not everyone will leave. That's just business. You are not a special snowflake who can't be replaced fairly easily. When you have more in depth experience and special skills that no one esle has, then they are more worried about retention. However, in any case, no company has the budget to give everyone raises at the level you think is appropriate. Expect 2-3% raises and be happy when you get more.

Comment: @HLGEM the problem is that a 2-3% raise won't make any effect at the end of the month AT ALL in Germany. That basically mean something like 30 euros extra! The taxes are high! So I doubt getting a 2-3% raise will satisfy/impress anyone since it's practical effect is almost zero!

Comment: The business doesn't care about your standard of living. They care about their budget and what you contribute to their bottom line. Very few people (less than 1% outside fo sales) contribute enough to warrant as large a raise as you want. In business the best way to get more than 2-3% is to get a new job or a promotion to a job with a higher payscale. Nobody gives raises at the level you think is good. Not to all employees. And at two years, you are not likely to be someone they feel needs the reward to be retained because your contribution to their bottom line is  likely not that great.

Comment: @JackTwain: You're only looking at your side of the equation. If you get e.g. a 3% raise, that might not be much more money in your pocket, but your employer still has to *pay* at least 3% more every month. That money has to come from somewhere. If your work is so good that it attracts new customers or existing customers will pay more for it, great; otherwise, where would your 40% raise come from?

Comment: @nikie: I'm quite sure the cost to the employer is more than just 3 % more, due to all employee insurances, taxes, mandatory payments etc that the employees in Europe never see in their tax card :) For example in Finland, if an employee wants a 100 EUR raise before personal taxes, the employee would need to earn 300 EUR (200 %) more money for the employer so that the employer can cover the extra costs and also make profit.

Comment: @HLGEM I think your comments aren't true of the tech industry. 2-3% raise would be enough to leave, but this also depends on what your skills are. According to Robert Half, Java developers in Germany can expect a 4.4 percent raise on average. I would think a good company would give more in the 6+% range as German unemployment, as well as EU unemployment, is falling and Tech jobs are getting harder to fill. While JackTwain may not be a snowflake, I'm sure hes also not a work horse. The tech industry is much more about individual talents and creativity. You can't stamp out talented workers.

Comment: @JackTwain Also, with software, a lot of big companies figure that it will take a new person 6 months to get comfortable in their new environment. Understanding legacy code is not an easy task. I agree: it would be foolish to let an employee walk rather than paying them. Even if you can hire someone with the same skillset for a lower price they won't have the same working knowledge of the codebase the other person had. Also, hiring someone in tech is risky. How well is that person at applying design patterns? Elegant engineer or hacker? If someone has proved themselves, pay them!

Comment: @punchingInAPepper, I work in the tech industry and those have been fairly standard raises in the US for at least 30 years in most moderately large companies (not startups which are a whole other kettle of fish, but most devs don't work in startups). I can even remember 4 years (2008-2012) when virtually no one I knew in any industry got a raise at all.

Comment: @HLGEM I've personally done better with the exception of this last year when I only got 2% (town is in hard times), and I'm looking for another job now. Often, switching companies may be the best was to get a raise. Take a look at this: https://www.roberthalf.com/sites/default/files/Media_Root/images/rht-pdfs/robert_half_technology_2016_salary_guide.pdf
And those aren't made up figures. You can search Robert Halfs site for jobs and see that the salaries really do line up.

Comment: New hire rates and salary increases for existing hires are not  at the same rate. You have been lucky not to get small raises, but they are the most common.  And certain geographic areas do better than others. But to expect higher raises is just unrealistic most places. Agree that you will get the best raises when you leave, that is why long term employees may be vastly underpaid compared to the market. If you are really valuable, you can use that to leverage a raise, but it will generally only work for 1-2 people at a given work site in a given year.